# Calculated column which references its previous value and current value

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a requirement where I am creating a calculated column. This column needs to use its own previous value and also its current value (i.e. to perform a cumulative calculation).
I know this is possible in Tableau by using the function

```
PREVIOUS_VALUE(-1)
```

so I can do something like

```
x (calc)  = sum(x(calc) + PREVIOUS_VALUE(-1))
```

[image: Sample result]

How can this be performed in Spotfire? In other words, what is the equivalent Spotfire function to

`PREVIOUS_VALUE(-1) (from Tableau)`

Here is the equivalent implementation on excel. Where [WDVpt2] is the calculated field.
[image: Cumulative calculation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by the following approach. Its a limitation of Spotfire that a calculated column can not refer its value at the previous node.In tableau Lookup and Previous_value supports this feature(not to be confused with Previous() of Spotfire which can be applied on a static column [x] so [X_Calc]= [X_Calc]+ [X_Calc] over(AllPrevious([ROWID])) is not possible

Step1:Create a ROW ID column which is based on perdiod Rowid([YEAR])

Step2:Breaking the result for each row into a separate calculated column so first row value

First(Sum([WDVpt1]) over (AllPrevious([RowID])) - (Sum([WDVpt1]) over AllPrevious([RowID])) * [Policy rate])) over (AllPrevious([RowID])))

Step3: Create columns for remaining periods(3 to 16) by using the previous calculated column Eg:- column for node 3 will use [WDVpt2_Year2] column for node 4 will use [WDVpt2_Year3] and so on Sum((case when [RowID]=2 then [WDVpt1] end) + Min([WDVpt1]) over ([RowID]) - (((case when [RowID]=2 then [WDVpt1] end) + Min([WDVpt2_Year2]) over (intersect([asset class code],[RowID]))) * [Policy rate])) over (AllPrevious([RowID])))

Step4: Write a case statement to generate one single column

case when [RowID]=2 then first([WDVpt2_Year2]) when [RowID]=3 then first([WDVpt2_Year3]) when [RowID]=4 then first([WDVpt2_Year4]) when [RowID]=5 then first([WDVpt2_Year5]) when [RowID]=6 then first([WDVpt2_Year6]) when [RowID]=7 then first([WDVpt2_Year7]) when [RowID]=8 then first([WDVpt2_Year8]) when [RowID]=9 then first([WDVpt2_Year9]) when [RowID]=10 then first [WDVpt2_Year10]) when [RowID]=11 then first([WDVpt2_Year11]) when [RowID]=12 then first([WDVpt2_Year12]) when [RowID]=13 then first([WDVpt2_Year13]) when [RowID]=14 then first([WDVpt2_Year14]) when [RowID]=15 then first([WDVpt2_Year15]) when [RowID]=16 then first([WDVpt2_Year16]) end as [WDVpt2]

Answer (score 1):

This is done with an `OVER` function. You can read about them from the [Tibco Documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.0/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_over_functions.htm). The formula you are looking for is:

```
(Sum([x]) over (AllPrevious([x]))) - [x]
```

> Uses all nodes, including the current, from the start of the level.
>   This can be used to calculate the cumulative sum.

Comment: I need a calculated column to be able to refer itself. In Tableau "Previous" is self referring, referring to the result of the calculated field it is a part of e.g PREVIOUS_VALUE(0)+SUM([Profit]) .So in our case its  sum(x(calc) + PREVIOUS_VALUE(-1)) that I wanted. Thanks

Comment: So, every previous node excluding the current?

Comment: Every previous node excluding the current and the following ones

Comment: I am actually trying to Perform a cumulative calculation, one which refers the calculated field's previous cell. I have performed that on excel. Please see the new attached screenshot. I am trying to calculate [WDVpt2] which is a cumulative calculation referring to its previous value

Comment: That’s exactally what this does. One uses the current cell and all previous and one only uses the previous cells

Comment: Your answer holds true if I calculate values only on one column [WDVpt1], however [WDVpt2] uses the previous node of [WDVp1](where your formula fits well) + also  uses the previous calculated value of [WDVp2](this is where the formula shuts down as I am not able to refer to the previous [WDVp2] value as its doen't exist). Please see the screenshot of that excel file. Thanks

Comment: I was able to get what I was looking for. please see my new comments. Thanks for your support :)